# How can I safely open, wire & close this E27 lamp holder?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

How can I safely open, wire & close this E27 lamp holder? I’m afraid without a proper guide I’ll end up breaking it or damaging the external or internals.

[image]

Update: Thanks to you I got it open (health issues) and I’m wondering what kind of connectors these are and how I am to bind the wires to them? Before I click  pop and close it again.

Ps: I stripped the wires a bit at the end after posting this. I’m wondering where they go & how they will remain bound / locked inside. Please don’t tell me these have to be soldered. This mechanism has got to have some secret that I don’t know.
[image: wire connectors inside]

Comment: And yes screwing on & off the rim/ holder ring is straight forward. But have no idea how to safely open the top back part to get to wire connectors etc

Comment: is there a screw hidden in that oval hole? as another option can you use a screwdriver in the rectangular hole to release the catch?

Comment: @ratchetfreak - No screw. What "direction" & "action" might I investigate in the rectangular hole/ slot?

Answer (score 19):

Slide a flat-bladed screwdriver into a rectangular hole in the back (rounded) end. Pry the inner (deepest) end of the locking tab outward gently while applying pressure to separate the bulb socket from the back cover at the joint that jogs its way around the middle. If you're not able to release the tab from the back, use a knife point from the outside, prying the tip of the tab outward.

When it releases slightly, do the same on the other side to fully release the back cover. You may want to slip a folded paper or other tool in the gap after you release the first tab to maintain separation.

Slide the wires through the back cover ports, make the connections, and snap the cover back on, making sure that both tabs engage.

[image]

<sub>[Image source](https://bermda.desertcart.com/products/59152566-e-27-light-bulb-holder-woopower-practical-lamp-pendant-socket-plastic-lampshade-ring-adapter-white)</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Regarding wiring, the two sets of two parallel round holes are for wires. It's a push to connect system, so to connect a wire you just push it in the hole about 1/2". To release them is a bit tricky. The smaller rectangular holes to the inside of wiring holes is for the release mechanism. A push pin works pretty well, and in my experience it's not easy to find the sweet spot. There are little aluminum tabs in there that need to be pressed in just the right way to release the wires. And you have to pull gently on the wires as you press the tab. I hope that's helpful to anyone reading. Best of luck.